# turn array of strings into a sentence with ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, join, methods

So i need to turn an array of strings into a sentence, capitalize the first word and add a period at the end.  I have looked everywhere and found bits and pieces but nothing as specific as my problem.

What i tried so far:

```
array1 = ["this", "is", "my", "first", "post"] 

def sentence_maker (array)

array.join(' ')

end
```

It makes a sentence but i can't figure out how to make the first word capitalized while keeping the others in lower case and add a "." at the end of the sentence.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Awesome! thanks everyone for chipping in.  I'm new to ruby and these answers are all helpful.  Much obliged.

Answer (score 5):

You could do as below :

```
array1 = ["this", "is", "my", "first", "post"] 

def sentence_maker (array)
  array.join(' ').capitalize << "."
end

sentence_maker(array1)
# => "This is my first post."
```

Answer (score 1):

How I would do it:

```
array1 = ["this", "is", "my", "first", "post"]

def sentence_maker(array)
   string = array.join(' ')
   string.capitalize!
   string << '.'
end

puts sentence_maker(array1)
#=> "This is my first post."
```

See: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to do this would be to use the [`capitalize` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-capitalize), but note that “case conversion is effective only in ASCII region”:

```
"école".capitalize
 # => "école"
```

If this is likely to be an issue you should look into using something like the [Unicode Utils gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/unicode_utils):

```
require 'unicode_utils'
UnicodeUtils.titlecase("école")
# => "École"
```

So your complete method might look something like:

```
def sentence_maker (array)

  array[0] = UnicodeUtils.titlecase(array[0])
  array.join(' ') << '.'

end
```

(This is a bit different from the other answers because `titlecase` changes the first letter of *each* word in the string, which we don’t want in this case. Also note this modifies `array` which you might not want, so you”d have to structure the code differently if that were the case.)